# AppleTV makes horrible noise on startup and when waking up from standby

Tags: appletv

I have an Insignia 25" LCD TV and an Apple TV Gen 2 connected to it via HDMI. When I wake the AppleTV up from sleep mode or boot it up from being turned off, it makes a loud, white noise-y sound. You can listen to the noise [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc9oF7RL1GQ).

The noise is most likely from the AppleTV, since the TV doesn't make the noise when it is on the DVD player input, and the noise starts exactly when the AppleTV light turns on.

Has anyone had this problem? If so, are there any known solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Is the Apple TV itself making noise or sending that noise out to the receiver / amplifier connected to normal speakers in your system?

Comment: The noise is coming out of the speakers built into the TV. The Apple TV itself is silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found to avoid the static on start up when using an ATV-2 with my Insignia NS-LTDVD26 LCD TV/DVD Combo via HDMI, is to never update it.  After updating, a problem with the aspect ratio changing during steaming videos from Netflix stopped for me, but the static started.  For me, even after the update, the static clears after moving the cursor around for a few seconds.  As a work around I start the ATV first and move the "would be cursor" around for a few seconds, then turn on my TV, this usually avoids the static problem, as it has usually cleared by the time the TV is powered on.  Perhaps not the best work around, but the best I know of so far, since muting has little effect.  The reason I know it is the update causing the problem, for this TV model, is that I took the ATV back to the Apple Store because of the static, and they replaced it with a new one.  I used the new one for several weeks without updating it, and had no static problems, however did have a problem with the aspect ratio changing during streaming Netflix videos.  As with my first ATV, soon as I updated it, the aspect ratio problem stopped, but the static problem came back.

Comment: Seems pretty likely that it is a software problem then, I'll see about filing a bug report, and hopefully new updates will fix this. Thank you for you detailed response.

Comment: I have filed a Bug Report with Apple, the tracking ID is  10999662, @Stephen Pilling, if you submitted one as well, it will probably get more developer attention and get resolved faster. Here is the site: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: After updating to Apple TV Software 5.0 (4099), the noise only lasts about half a second, @Stephen Pilling try updating and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is as you correctly described static.

This will be due to the connection, not the Apple TV its self. You will need to confirm this by.

- using the Apple TV with another television
- use another HDMI cable (go for one with gold connectors)

I would check the cable first as it sounds like something is interfering with the signal.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, I'll try this out when I get home.

Comment: After trying another HDMI cable, the same problem arises, it is not an issue with the cable.

Comment: ans another TV set?